# 'Bad file mode' error OPEN statement read/write to serial (COM) port using VB6

Tags: visual-studio, serial-port, basic, qbasic

I try to migrate an old QBasic program, for reading from a serial device (COM-port), to Visual Basic 6.

I use this code (this original code should work for VB6 also):

```
RESET
OPEN "COM1:2400,E,7,2,CS,DS,CD" FOR RANDOM AS #1
PRINT #1, "SND1"
LINE INPUT #1, P$
```

This works fine with QBasic (sending 'SND1' gives me the data from the device), but VB6 gives an error at the `PRINT`-command: 'Bad file mode' (error 54).

If I change `FOR RANDOM` to `FOR OUTPUT` the `PRINT`-commands works, but then the `LINE INPUT`-command gives the same error (of course).

UPDATE:

The only options for 'mode' (see: [http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa266177(v=vs.60).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa266177%28v=vs.60%29.aspx)) are Append, Binary, Input, Output, or Random.

Comment: can't you open the COM1 port for **read** and write?

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa266177(v=vs.60).aspx only gives the options: Append, Binary, Input, Output, or Random

Comment: can you do INPUT|OUTPUT, OR'ing?

Comment: No, this is no correct syntax, see: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa266177(v=vs.60).aspx

Comment: how about my answer?  writing, closing and reading?

Comment: If you use open for output you can only print to it. If you open for input you can only read from it. If you open for random you can do both.

Comment: You need to use GET and PUT with a file opened for RANDOM.

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
OPEN "COM1:2400,E,7,2,CS,DS,CD" FOR OUTPUT AS #1
PRINT #1, "SND1"
CLOSE #1
OPEN "COM1:2400,E,7,2,CS,DS,CD" FOR INPUT AS #1
LINE INPUT #1, P$
```

Comment: well, I can't test it but my "hope" is that writing would occur for the first open.  We close it and then open it for writing.  total guess!

Comment: Now I get an error ('Input past end of file') at the `LINE INPUT`. May be something to do with the communication protocol, I 've to figure that out first

Comment: doesn't line input mean it's needing/waiting for a CRLF?

Answer (score 1):

This snip describes using GET/PUT to access a file opened for RANDOM in QB:

```
OPEN "COM1:9600,N,8,1,BIN,CS0,DS0" FOR RANDOM AS #1
DO
    IF LOC(1) THEN
        GET 1, , x
        PRINT CHR$(x);
    END IF
    x$ = INKEY$
    IF LEN(x$) THEN
        IF x$ = CHR$(27) THEN END
        x = ASC(x$)
        PUT 1, , x
    END IF
LOOP
END
```